# Form Sanitize using filter_var() and html entities() in PHP

Tags: php

My input must be validated using  filter_var()  and  html_entities().

Heres my code which doesn't work:

```
session_start();

if(empty($_POST['add']) === false ) {

    $name =    filter_var(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email =   filter_var(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $phone =   filter_var(INPUT_POST, 'phone', FILTER_SANITIZE_INT);
    $address = filter_var(INPUT_POST, 'address', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


}
?>
```

When i do a test and put "**Frost**" into my Name input it comes out in bold but its not suppose to. After this is done It needs to write out to the $_SESSION['cart']. Im lost at this point

Comment: What did you put into 'name' to make it bold? Show the code you are using to display it.

Comment: You are using the `filter_var`-function with `filter_input`-arguments. Are you sure this is your code???

Comment: I am using a debug module to view it. This is my code, i am new to PHP, please excuse my mistakes:

Comment: $_GET contains:
Array
(
    [name] => <b>Frost<b/>
    [email] => 
    [phone] => 
    [address] => 
)

Answer (score 0):

From the comments so far I can see:
If your $_GET variable contains that array, you are not posting the HTML form right. Use this for POST-ing a HTML `<form>`:

`<form action="/path/to/script.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!-- input fields -->
</form>`

Also, like Peter van der Wal said, use the `filter_input()` function instead of `filter_var()` if you want to use `INPUT_POST`. Otherwise use `filter_var($_POST['input_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)`.

For more help post more HTML code

If you are new to coding/PHP I suggest you familiarize yourself with [W3Schools](http://w3schools.com/) and [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/). Quite useful if you understand these resources. Good way to start learning.

Answer (score 0):

So at this point I need to submit the form to itself for testing purposes, now heres my code at this current time:

```
   <?php

 session_start();
 if(empty($_POST['add']) === false ) {

$name =    filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email =   filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$phone =   filter_var($_POST['phone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_INT);
$address = filter_var($_POST['address'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


}
?>
    <form method="post" action="cart.php" id="form1">

        <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <br><br>
        <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
        <input type="email" name="email">
        <br><br>
        <label for="tel">Phone:</label><br>
        <input type="tel" name="phone">
        <br><br>
        <label for="textarea">Address:</label><br>
        <input type="textarea" name="address">
        <br>

        <div id="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember">
        </div> 

        <div id="label1">
            <label for="checkbox">Remember Me</label>       
        </div>


        <br>
        <br>


            <input type="submit" value="Submit">   

    </form>
```

I also have a debug module on the page and now its in the $_POST array instead go GET which is good but when I put html entities inside the name input field they still aren't being sanitised/removed.

Debug Module:

```
$_POST contains:
Array
(
[name] => Frost
[email] => 
[phone] => 
[address] => 
)
```

*Frost shows in bold when I add the BOLD html tag into its input field but the whole point of this is to stop that from happening.